# Android CalendarView unable to select dates after height change

Tags: java, android, calendarview

I have a CalendarView that has an initial height of 0dp and I would like to show it on button click by increasing its height.

It is in a vertical linear layout with weight 0 and height 0dp, so it's not visible.

Now when i click the button i run the following code:

```
CalendarView v = (CalendarView)this.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = 888;
v.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

This indeed makes the view completely visible, however as a side effect I can now no longer select any dates in the calendarView I am only able interact with the buttons that change the month.

How can I make the calendarView clickable again?

Comment: try v.invalidate() may be help you

Comment: Do you have any luck solving the issue?